# How to create a new view every time navigation occurs in PRISM?

Tags: c#, wpf, prism-4

I'm using WPF4 and PRISM4 for my new project.

There is a single module with several views in it. The DI is done with unity. When I navigate from ViewA to ViewB for the first time, the ViewB is created and its constructor is called. But when I try to navigate to ViewB for the second, third time, the ViewB is not created, but existing instance is reused.

I'm using *IRegionManager.RequestNavigate* for my navigation purposes.

I've tried to pass *TransientLifeTimeManager* to *RegisterType* Unity methods, but to no avail.

Is there a way to configure prism and/or unity to create a new view every time I navigate to it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The way to do it is to implement IRegionMemberLifetime on your either your view or viewModel, and return false in the boolean property KeepAlive as follows:

```
public class EmployeeDetailsViewModel : IRegionMemberLifetime
{
    public bool KeepAlive
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not quite correct, because it has the side effect that if the user switches active views through the UI then your `EmployeeDetailsView` will be removed from the region instead of simply being deactivated.

Comment: I am indeed assuming that he wants to remove the view when it's navigated from, and if I'm mistaken then he would have corrected me. We are interpreting his request differently - I really don't see why this would make you vote -1, as if my answer is incorrect.

Answer (score 20):

The correct way to do this is by implementing `INavigationAware` either in your View or your ViewModel (Prism will check first the view, and if it doesn't implement `INavigationAware` it will also check the ViewModel).

You are interested specifically in the `IsNavigationTarget` method, which tells Prism if the current instance of the View should be reused, or if another instance should be created to satisfy the navigation request. So, to always create a new View you would do:

```
public class MyViewModel : INavigationAware {
    bool INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }

    void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }
}
```

All of this is explained in greater detail in Chapter 8 of the Prism 4 documentation; they also have [an illustration of how it works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg430861%28v=pandp.40%29.aspx#TheRegionNavigationSequence), which is very nice because it also lets you know exactly where you can hook in and how.

Comment: A small addendum, if using MEF for dependency injection you should ensure that your view has the attribute `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)`. Otherwise, the `ServiceLocator` will return the same instance regardless of the `IsNavigateTarget` logic. The navigation service sees that the region already contains the instance and activates it. I was puzzled for a long time.

Comment: This actually fixed my opposite problem.  My condition was incorrect thus returning false all the time.

Answer (score 1):

It internally looks for a View in *ActiveViews* property of a region. If it does not exist in there, it creates a new one and adds it to *ActiveViews* for future use.

To accomplish what you want to do, you will need to remove or clear *ActiveView* collection before navigating to any View.

### Example:

```
public static class RegionManagerExtensions
{
    public static void RequestNavigateEx(this IRegionManager regionManager, String regionName, Uri source)
    {
        if (regionManager != null)
        {
            IRegion region = regionManager.Regions[regionName];

            if (region != null)
            {
                foreach (Object view in region.ActiveViews)
                {
                    region.Remove(view);
                }

                regionManager.RequestNavigate(regionName, source);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, I tried to do this and end up with a blank view. is there something i'm missing?

Comment: The view doesn't have to exist in the *Active View* property; the view also won't be recreated if it exists in the **Views** property.