# Issues with INavigationAware in Prism 5

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism-5

I'm fairly new to WPF and MVVM with Prism and I'm having an issue with Prism navigation.  Each time I navigate to a particular view, I want to load a new view; however, if I enter some data or fully process some data, navigate away and come back, the existing data is always kept in the view.

I have read similar issues here on SO such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115484/how-to-create-a-new-view-every-time-navigation-occurs-in-prism) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5648115/c-sharp-prism-navigationproblem).  Both point to using `INavigationAware` or `IRegionMemberLifetime`.  I have tried to implement both in my ViewModel; however, none seem to solve the issue for me.

If I use `INavigationAware` and set `IsNavigationTarget` to false, the view never loads.  If I use `IRegionMemberLifetime` and set `KeepAlive` to false, it still retains my data.

I could post code; however, it's simple and looks like the same that's in the linked issues.  Has anyone had similar issues with Prism navigation?

Any help is appreciated.

*Edit - Adding sample code*

In an effort to get rid of any red herrings with other code I've got, I created a new Prism app with the bare necessities.  My issue with the view not displaying when navigating back has cleared up; however, the view is still retaining the entered values.

Here is some sample code:

Model:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    public string ObjectName { get; set; }

}
```

I created a basic view with just two TextBox controls, 1 bound and 1 not:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="ModuleA" />
    <TextBox Text="{Binding DisplayedSomeObject.ObjectName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
    <TextBox />
</StackPanel>
```

ViewModel:

```
[Export]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]
[RegionMemberLifetime(KeepAlive=false)]
public class ModuleAViewModel : BindableBase, IConfirmNavigationRequest, INavigationAware
{
    private SomeObject displayedSomeObject = new SomeObject();
    public SomeObject DisplayedSomeObject
    {
        get { return displayedSomeObject; }
        set
        {
            displayedSomeObject = value;
        }
    }

    [ImportingConstructor]
    public ModuleAViewModel()
    {

    }

    void IConfirmNavigationRequest.ConfirmNavigationRequest(NavigationContext navigationContext, Action<bool> continuationCallback)
    {
        continuationCallback(true);
    }


    bool INavigationAware.IsNavigationTarget(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        return false;
    }

    void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedFrom(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
    }

    void INavigationAware.OnNavigatedTo(NavigationContext navigationContext)
    {
        var newSomeObject = new SomeObject();
        this.DisplayedSomeObject = newSomeObject;
    }
}
```

When I run this, both the bound and un-bound controls retain their values when navigated back to.

Comment: Do you register your viewmodels / views in a DI container? Please post your sample viewmodel code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you done some troubleshooting on Navigation? Set a breakpoint to when the page is navigated to and see how all the data is coming back in. I thought I had the same problem before and I was foolishly loading a object into my VM that was never getting destroyed.

Because of this, it appeared the VM was being kept alive, but in reality it was not. It would load like normal every time, but it would be pulling from the object that wasn't reloading.

So, set a breakpoint on the navigateTo and step through to see if the data is getting reloaded or not.

EDIT:
Looking at the code above, I believe you need to add IRegionMemberLifetime as well. I am currently using Prism 4.5, so I don't know if this has changed in 5, but I have to add that for it to actually destroy it.

```
public class ModuleAViewModel : BindableBase, IConfirmNavigationRequest, INavigationAware, IRegionMemberLifetime
{
 ...
        bool IRegionMemberLifetime.KeepAlive
    {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  I've added a breakpoint and it's hitting OnNavigatedTo, but as you can see in my code I added above, all I'm wanting to do is instantiate a new instance of the object and assign it.  I'm not seeing anything pass to it that shouldn't be there.

Comment: Edited my response above - Try adding IRegionMemberLifeTime to ModuleAViewModel.

Comment: I was implementing RegionMemberLifetime as an attribute in my VM.  I went ahead and implemented the interface instead to test, but it's still retaining the values in the TextBox controls.  I put a breakpoint on the getter and it is reaching the code.  I'm not sure what I'm missing at this point.

Comment: How are you resolving your view/vm? The only thing I can think of that is left is that you might be registering your view/vm as a singleton instance in your IoC container. It it is being registered as a singleton it would never get a new instance. After that, I am pretty much out of idea.s.

Comment: I think you've got me going in the right direction; I've had my struggles with MEF in the past, so that could be the culprit.  Let me dig into that.

Comment: OK, so the remaining issue was an issue on my SomeObject instantiation.  I wasn't implementing anything on the setter so that explains why nothing was changing on the display.  You helped me get my Navigation interfaces straightened out and it helped me to ensure the object was getting re-instantiated.  Thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad you got it figured out!